# Spring Security authentication via token

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a server with an API. Server is protected by Spring Security.

I want to have an access to the API from an external applications using tokens in request parameters

Firstly user will go to a service which gives him a token and then access the API with this token.

But I want to preserve previous access to the API through standard Spring Security solutions.

So, could you please help me, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to implement custom AuthenticationFilter like this

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  private static final String SECURITY_TOKEN_KEY    = "token";
  private static final String SECURITY_TOKEN_HEADER = "X-Token";
  private String token = null;

  protected CustomAuthenticationFilter() {
    super("/");
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    this.token = request.getParameter(SECURITY_TOKEN_KEY);
    // or this.token = request.getHeader(SECURITY_TOKEN_HEADER);

    if (request.getAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED) != null) {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }

    request.setAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED, Boolean.TRUE);

    if(request.getParameter(actionParameter) !=null &&
        request.getParameter(actionParameter).equals("logout")) {
      SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
      return;
    }

    if (!requiresAuthentication(request, response)) {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }

    Authentication authResult;
    try {
      authResult = attemptAuthentication(request, response);
      if (authResult == null) {
        return;
      }
    } catch (AuthenticationException failed) {
      unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
      return;
    }

    try {
      successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    } catch (NestedServletException e) {
      if(e.getCause() instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
        unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, new LockedException("Forbidden"));
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

    AbstractAuthenticationToken userAuthenticationToken = authUserByToken(this.token);
    if(userAuthenticationToken == null)
      throw new AuthenticationServiceException(MessageFormat.format("Error | {0}", "Bad Token"));

    return userAuthenticationToken;
  }

  private AbstractAuthenticationToken authUserByToken(String tokenRaw) {
    AbstractAuthenticationToken authToken = null;
    try {
      // check your input token, identify the user
      // if success create AbstractAuthenticationToken for user to return
      // eg:
      authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, userHash, userAuthorities);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Error during authUserByToken", e);
    }
    return authToken;
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                          Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);

    getSuccessHandler().onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authResult);
  }

}
```

and custom SuccessHandler like this

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  @Override
  protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return request.getServletPath();
  }

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getServletPath()).forward(request, response);
  }
}
```

and wire it in spring config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

  <context:annotation-config/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.your.path" />

  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

  <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true"
                          access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>

  <http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true"
        auto-config="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <custom-filter ref="restFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <logout/>
  </http>

  <b:bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>

  <b:bean id="restFilter" class="com.your.path.CustomAuthenticationFilter">
    <b:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="mySuccessHandler"/>
  </b:bean>

  <b:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="com.your.path.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

  <b:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <b:property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="true"/>
    <b:property name="decisionVoters">
      <b:list>
        <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
          <b:property name="rolePrefix" value=""/>
        </b:bean>
        <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
      </b:list>
    </b:property>
  </b:bean>

</b:beans>
```

this should help.

Comment: Is there no token based authentication filter on spring security??

Comment: I tried your code, but i have a problem . When an error occurs the doFilter is called infinitely, and StackOverflowError is shown. This happens only if there is an error in the request.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using following bean in spring security [TimedKeyBasedPersistenceTokenService](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/token/KeyBasedPersistenceTokenService.html)

```
<bean name="tokenService" class="com.digipos.security.core.token.TimedKeyBasedPersistenceTokenService">
    <property name="tokenLifeInMinutes" value="15000"/>
    <property name="serverSecret" value="1234567"/>
    <property name="serverInteger" value="15062013"/>
    <property name="pseudoRandomNumberBits" value="7"/>
    <property name="secureRandom" ref="secureRandom"/>
</bean>


<bean name="secureRandom" class="java.security.SecureRandom">
    <property name="seed" value="122"/>
</bean>
```

Apart from that you also need to

use a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider`

and `entry-point-ref` attribute of `<http>` to `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint` bean

Comment: I am very interested in this token based authentication but does not understand the relation with PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider ... does not the token need to be verified in order to authenticate? ... can you elaborate this a bit more?

Answer (score 3):

I have found an easier way :

My solution works for token authentication, and form authentication, but you can easily disable one of them if you want.

My filter is similar to Roman's filter, but I don't need the check if the user has access to a particular resource, also no logout handled -> passed to springSecurity.

auth filter :

```
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

private static final String SECURITY_TOKEN_KEY = "token";
private static final String SECURITY_TOKEN_HEADER = "X-Token";

public TokenAuthenticationFilter() {

    super( "/" );
}

@Override
public void doFilter( ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    String token = request.getParameter( SECURITY_TOKEN_KEY );
    // or this.token = request.getHeader(SECURITY_TOKEN_HEADER);

    if ( token != null ) {

        Authentication authResult;
        try {
            authResult = attemptAuthentication( request, response, token );
            if ( authResult == null ) {
                notAuthenticated( request, response, new LockedException( "User Not found" ) );
                return;
            }
        } catch ( AuthenticationException failed ) {
            notAuthenticated( request, response, failed );
            return;
        }

        try {
            successfulAuthentication( request, response, chain, authResult );
            return;
        } catch ( NestedServletException e ) {
            logger.error( e.getMessage( ), e );
            if ( e.getCause( ) instanceof AccessDeniedException ) {
                notAuthenticated( request, response, new LockedException( "Forbidden" ) );
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter( request, response );// return to others spring security filters
}

public void notAuthenticated( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed ) throws IOException {

    response.sendRedirect( "http://www.google.ro" );
    // unsuccessfulAuthentication( request, response, failed );
}

public Authentication attemptAuthentication( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String token ) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

    AbstractAuthenticationToken userAuthenticationToken = authUserByToken( token );
    if ( userAuthenticationToken == null )
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException( MessageFormat.format( "Error | {0}", "Bad Token" ) );

    return userAuthenticationToken;
}

private AbstractAuthenticationToken authUserByToken( String tokenRaw ) {

    AbstractAuthenticationToken authToken = null;
    try {
        // check your input token, identify the user
        // if success create AbstractAuthenticationToken for user to return
        // eg:
        // authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( username, userHash, userAuthorities );
        // authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( tokenRaw, authToken, )
        logger.info( "token received = " + tokenRaw );
        // obtain user by your methods
        // if ( user != null ) {
        // SecurityUser securityUser = new SecurityUser( user );
        // return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken( securityUser, securityUser.getPassword( ), securityUser.getAuthorities( ) );
        // }
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        logger.error( "Error during authUserByToken", e );
    }
    return authToken;
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult ) throws IOException, ServletException {

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext( ).setAuthentication( authResult );

    new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler( ).onAuthenticationSuccess( request, response, authResult );
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

    logger.error( "No TOKEN PROVIDED" );
    return null;
    }

}
```

then all you have to do to map this filter is configuring it in springSecurity(addFilterBefore), this does not have to be mapped in servlet config.

```
        http.authorizeRequests( ).antMatchers( "/login*" ).permitAll( );
        http.authorizeRequests( ).antMatchers( "/register*" ).permitAll( );

        http.authorizeRequests( ).antMatchers( "/admin/**" ).hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER" );//

        http.authorizeRequests( ).and( ).formLogin( )//
                .loginPage( "/login" )//
                .successHandler( successHandler( ) )//
                .failureUrl( "/login?error" ).permitAll( )//
                .and( ).logout( )//
                .logoutUrl( "/logout" ).logoutSuccessUrl( "/login?logout" ).permitAll( )//
                .and( ).rememberMe( ).key( applicationName + "_key" ).tokenValiditySeconds( 2419200 ); // remember me for 2 weeks

        http.addFilterBefore( new TokenAuthenticationFilter( ), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class );
```

Comment: I have a question on all this?  When a token is generated on the backend, what is generating the token, and how is it being stored/persisted on the backend?   How long is it around for?   And when we get an AJAX request to the backend, with the token ... I see we have some code to lookup that token from the token store, is that correct?  When the token is generated on the backend and stored, when we send the token to the front-end, do you store it as a cookie?   What if cookies are turned off?   Thanks!

Comment: It just depends on your needs. JWT does not need a store for example. it has information inside it. Otherwise you will need a token validation api(store/check/invalidate). if you are talking about AJAX req.. again you can add it to local storage, after obtaining, or cookies, or just some variable in the page.. it depends a lot of your targets/needs. In general I use this to authenticate api consumers, and I have a local cache take from db with <token,auth_info>