# Spring Security + Token based service calls

Tags: json, spring, token

I have backend services which are build using spring+hibernate+rest, every rest service url accept Json as input and gives json as response to forntend(web,Android,Ios), after login we send one unique random number to frontend, to access/call further services he uses this unique number, now i want to implement spring security and i want to implement token based communication insted of unique random number...Any Solution? i also need startup sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Spring security has no out of the box implementation of token security. You will find some clues in following posts :

- [Token authentication based with spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153339/token-authentication-based-with-spring-security)
- [Spring Security authentication via token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126201/spring-security-authentication-via-token)

I had to implement it myself and it was not that simple ... The evident part is that you will need a Filter. My requirements was that the token had a time limited validity, and could be used even if the application was deployed on several servers (redundancy) so I stored the tokens in database. I ended with :

- a `TokenAuthenticationFilter` positioned as a PRE_AUTH_FILTER with the following `doFilter` method :

  ```
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest sr, ServletResponse sr1, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
      boolean tokenAuthenticated = false;
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) sr;
      String token = findToken(request);
      if ((null == token) || (!authenticationNeeded(request))) {
          fc.doFilter(sr, sr1);
          return;
      }
      if (needHttps && (! request.isSecure())) {
          TokenAuthenticationToken at = new TokenAuthenticationToken(token);
          try {
              at.setDetails(detailsSource.buildDetails(request));
              Authentication auth = manager.authenticate(at);
              if ((auth != null) && (auth.isAuthenticated())) {
                  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
                  tokenAuthenticated = true;
              }
          } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
              logger.debug("Authentication failed :", e);
          }
      }
      else {
          logger.info("Token identification rejected : proto != https");
      }
      fc.doFilter(sr, sr1);
      if (tokenAuthenticated) {
          logger.debug("Token authenticated : invalidate session");
          HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
          if (session != null) {
              session.invalidate();
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- a `JdbcTokenAuthenticationProvider` ( using the `TokenAuthenticationToken` set by previous filter) to separate the filter part from the true authentication part (and stick to common `AuthenticationManager` usage)
- a `JdbcTokenAuthenticationManager` to do the DAO part, including Token creation and database cleaning

Hope it helps ...